# AWS Glue Data Handling and Bookmark Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

We're currently encountering two challenges with AWS Glue, and we would greatly appreciate assistance in addressing them:

1. **Issue with Data Deletion in Source S3 Bucket**: Occasionally, while our Spark job is in progress, data in the source S3 bucket gets deleted or modified. In such cases, the Glue job fails and generates an error. We are seeking guidance on how to gracefully handle these scenarios when data changes or is removed at the source while the Glue job is running.
2. **Bookmark-Enabled Glue Job Error on Subsequent Runs**: The second issue is more worrisome. Our Glue job, which is configured with bookmark, performs flawlessly during its initial run, successfully loading data into the target S3 bucket. However, on immediate subsequent runs, it encounters an error: "AnalysisException: Column 'id' does not exist. Did you mean one of the following? [];" Our assumption is that because there haven't been any changes in the source data, and no new data needs to be loaded, the script fails when attempting to read the "id" column at line number 55.

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Get job arguments, including the job name
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME',
                                     'environment',
                                     'landing_zone_s3_bucket_name',
                                     'raw_zone_non_sensitive_s3_bucket_name'])

# Create a SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

# Initialize GlueContext and SparkSession
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
logger = glueContext.get_logger()

# Create a Glue job
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

table_name = "profile"
environment = args['environment']
logger.info(environment)

# landing zone s3 bucket name
landing_zone_s3_bucket_name = args['landing_zone_s3_bucket_name']

raw_zone_non_sensitive_s3_bucket_name = args['raw_zone_non_sensitive_s3_bucket_name']
raw_zone_s3_location = f"s3://{raw_zone_non_sensitive_s3_bucket_name}/{table_name}"

try:
    # Load data from the Glue catalog into a DynamicFrame
    landing_zone_data_source = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database=landing_zone_s3_bucket_name,
        table_name=table_name,
        transformation_ctx=f"{environment}_landing_zone_non_sensitive_profile"
    )


    # Convert DynamicFrame to a DataFrame for further processing
    dataframe = landing_zone_data_source.toDF()

    # Drop PII columns from the DataFrame
    dataframe = dataframe.drop('email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'mobile')

    # Hash the 'id' column and rename it to 'HashedID'
    df_hashed = dataframe.withColumn('HashedID', sha2(col('id'), 256)).drop(col('id'))
    df_hashed = df_hashed.withColumnRenamed('HashedID', 'id')

    # Convert the DataFrame back to a DynamicFrame
    mapped_dyF = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df_hashed, glueContext, "hashed_df")

    # Write the DynamicFrame to an S3 bucket as Glue Parquet format
    S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=mapped_dyF,
        connection_type="s3",
        format="glueparquet",
        connection_options={
            "path": raw_zone_s3_location,
            "partitionKeys": [],  # You can specify partition keys if needed
        },
        format_options={"compression": "snappy"},  # Specify compression options
        transformation_ctx=f"{environment}_raw_zone_non_sensitive_profile",
    )
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(f"File not found")
finally:
    # Commit the job to update bookmarks
    job.commit()
```